# Does anyone know which ui class can show the red delete icon on the left top corner?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uikit, editing

When you use your safari on iphone, you can see the page control on the right bottom corner.
If you press this button, all pages will show, also they can be edited too.

I try to do the similar thing like this.
I want to press my edit button on the toolbar, then all the subview will appear a delete control on the left top corner(right top corner all ok). I tried to use the tableviewcell(setEditing method), it show the delete control, but isn't appear on the top corner.

Do you have any ideas? Or, Am I doing something wrong by using tableviewcell?

Answer (score 1):

A table-view cell definitely isn't the right approach here. That editing control is a custom one, probably a generic UIButton with a red-encircled X graphic. There isn't a built-in class that'll give you the behavior you're looking for; you'll have to roll your own, probably using a `UIScrollView` (with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`) with your “page” views laid out in a row inside it.